HAProxy how to set a port to get requests and send them to another server using ip of haproxy but not the client ip
Can I get haproxy to redirect requests(GET PUT POST) to a particular server and send back response using ip of haproxy?
I have a client that is allowing requests only from dedicated list of ip's, and need to be able to send requests not only from haproxy server(which ip is allowed) but from other workstations/applications
something like this work seems not working, my knowledge is poor in haproxy
frontend octo_front
   bind *:3090
   default_backend octo_back

backend octo_back
   server octouz https://needed.url%[capture.req.uri] check


Some more reading the documentation helped
this is the configuration that worked for me
frontend sandbox_octo_front
    bind *:3099
    option forwardfor
    default_backend octo_back

backend sandbox_octo_back
    mode http 
    option forwardfor
    http-request replace-header Host .* needed.url 
    server octouz needed.url:443 ssl verify none


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
